# How to be able copy text header on active tab

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to copy the header of an active tab, but I can't highlight the text on the active tab.
I tried this, but I can't make it work.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#" class="enableSelect">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>


.enableSelect {
    -moz-user-select: text;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    -ms-user-select: text;
}
```

[Tabs example](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=tabs)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its not fully supported this is what mozilla's website says

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not
>   use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every
>   user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
>   implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Use jquery to toggle active links

```
$(function() {
   $("li").click(function() {
      // remove classes from all
      $("li").removeClass("enableSelect");
      // add class to the one we clicked
      $(this).addClass("enableSelect");
   });
});
```

Or you can use this to get text of click element

```
 $(function() {
       $("li").click(function() {
          var text = $(this).text()
       });
   });
```

Comment: Hi this just add the class to the tab, but the class is still not working, I can't select any text from the header active tabs.

Comment: This is a nice idea, but I don't get why the text is unselectable, the users want to be able to copy the header or parts of it, with your solution all the text is always selected.